# What's fishy in my proof of the theorem "Every closed subset of a compact set is compact."?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Let $X$ be a metric space. Let $E\subset X$ be a compact subset of $X$ and let $F\subset E$ be a closed subset of $E$.

This is how I tried to prove the theorem:

**Suppose, on the contrary that $F$ is not compact.** This implies that no open cover of $F$ contains a finite subcover.

Since, $E$ is compact relative to $X$, there exist finite no. of open sets (in $X$) $V_1,V_2,...V_n$ such that 
 $E\subset V_1\cup V_2\cup \cdots\cup V_n$ 
Since, $F\subset E$, we have $F\subset V_1\cup V_2\cup \cdots\cup V_n\implies F$ is compact relative to $X $ $\tag{1}$.  
Now, it is known that if $F\subset E\subset X$, then $F$ is compact relative to $X$ if and only if $F$ is compact relative to $E$. 
  Hence by $(1)$: $ F$ is compact relative to $E$, which is a contradiction.

Has something gone wrong in this proof? I think so because no where have I used the fact that "$F$ is a closed subset." Please help. Thanks.

Comment: The fact that $F$ is not compact does not imply that no open cover of F contains a finite subcover, but that at least one open cover of F does not contain a finite subcover.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe: Of course. You are right.

Comment: The most egregious mistake is that “$F$ isn’t compact” means “there is an open cover without any finite subcover”, not “no open cover has a finite subcover”. Note also that “relative compactness” is the same as “compactness in the subspace topology”.

Comment: You seem to think the definition of compact is: $E$ is compact if there are a finite number of open sets $V_1, \ldots, V_n$ so that $E \subseteq V_1 \cup \cdots \cup V_n$. That's not right.

Comment: Then, you are using strangely the compacity : you say that $E$ is compact implies that $E$ can be covered by open sets... But every set can be covered by open sets (take just $X$ as a covering open set). This is not what compact means.

Comment: If that were the definition, every set would be compact. (exercise)

Comment: @JairTaylor: Tbh, this is what I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write

> **Suppose, on the contrary that $F$ is not compact.** This implies that no open cover of $F$ contains a finite subcover.

This is wrong. If $F$ is not compact, then there exists *at least one* open cover of $F$ that doesn't contain a finite subcover.

Just think to $X$, which provides an open cover of $F$ and *is* finite.

You go on with another incorrect statement. If $E$ is compact, not only it is the covered by a finite number of open sets (this is trivial, just take $X$ itself), but *every open cover of $E$ contains a finite subcover*.

This is the crux of compactness: *every open cover contains a finite subcover*, the negation of which is *there is an open cover that contains no finite subcover*.

---

The proof is actually quite simple and doesn't require contradiction. Take an open cover $\mathcal{V}$ of $F$. Since $F$ is closed in $E$, there exists a closed set $C$ in $X$ such that $F=E\cap C$. Now add $V=X\setminus C$, which is an open set in $X$. Then $\mathcal{V}\cup\{V\}$ is an open cover of $E$, so you can find $V_1,V_2,\dots,V_n\in\mathcal{V}$ such that
$$
E\subseteq V\cup V_1\cup V_2\cup\dots\cup V_n
$$
Therefore $F\subseteq V_1\cup V_2\cup\dots\cup V_n$.

*Remark 1.* Maybe it's not required to use $V$ in the finite subcover, but adding it does not change finiteness and allows to finish the proof.

*Remark 2.* It's actually not restrictive to assume $E=X$, because compactness is an “absolute” property: it doesn't depend on what space $E$ is embedded in. Proving this useful property is an interesting exercise.

*Remark 3.* You *could* go by contradiction. Suppose there is an open cover $\mathcal{V}$ of $F$ that contains no finite subcover. Then, using the same symbols as before, $\mathcal{V}\cup\{V\}$ is an open cover of $E$ that cannot contain a finite subcover, because this would also be a finite subcover of $F$.

Answer (score 3):

Where your proof went wrong is violating the definition of compactness of $E$ relative to $X$. This does **NOT** mean

> ... there exist finite no. of open sets (in $X$) $V_1,V_2,...V_n$ such that $$E\subset V_1\cup V_2\cup \cdots\cup V_n$$

Instead, what compactness of $E$ relative to $X$ means is

> ... for every collection of open sets $\{V_i\}_{i \in I}$ (in $X$) such that
> $$E \subset \bigcup_{i \in I} V_i
> $$
> there exists a finite sub collection $V_{i_1},V_{i_2},...,V_{i_n}$ such that
> $$E \subset V_{i_1} \cup V_{i_2} \cup \cdots \cup V_{i_N}
> $$

Comment: That should say ... for every collection of open sets $\{V_i\}_{i \in I}$ (in $X$) that covers $E$ (etc.).+1.

Comment: Heh, that's what I get for trying to copy the question text too closely.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So I negated the definition incorrectly. But then how would you recommend proving the theorem using contradiction?

Comment: A little background on the question: It's a theorem in Rudin's Mathematical analysis (chapter 2). I am trying to prove it using contradiction.

Comment: I would not recommend using contradiction at all. Use direct proof instead: choose a collection of open subsets of $X$ that covers $F$ and go from there.